# Android getauthutil getToken not returning a JWT

Tags: android, authorization

All,

I am writing an android app and i am trying to use Google+ as my account manager.

I have followed [excellent article here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) and i am prompted to sign into google+ and I event get a token back.

The problem is that the token does not appear to be a JWT ( i know this because there are only 2 dotted parts to the name instead of 3 and that when I pass the "token" to the java referenced in the same article I get an exception suggesting that the all is not well with the token :

```
com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:76)
        at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
        at com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebSignature$Parser.parse(JsonWebSignature.java:473)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.parse(GoogleIdToken.java:57)
        at Checker.check(Checker.java:34)
```

The code looks like this :-

```
    String scope = "oauth2:server:client_id:";

    scope += scope_; // my client id in the web section
    scope += ":api_scope:";

    String googleauth;
    googleauth ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";

 scope+=googleauth;
 try 
 {
     String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(act_,  s_account, scope);

       ....
```

The application does ask for verification and I permit it (and call getToken again as you are supposed to).

But the token appears to be unusable, its bound to be something silly, but as yet I cannot see what.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is, but I've read in several places that you need to put some sort of workaround in place to make it work with the Google authentication. You can have a look at http://www.trajano.net/2014/07/parsing-the-json-web-token-in-java/

Hope this helps